# getting "undefined reference to `get_driver_instance' "error

Tags: c++, mysql, compiler-errors, ubuntu-12.04, mysql-connector

I have installed mysql-C++ Connector using Synaptic Package manager.
I am using Ubuntu-12.04
my program is as below as given on Mysql site-

```
/* Standard C++ headers */
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

/* MySQL Connector/C++ specific headers */
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/connection.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/metadata.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset_metadata.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/warning.h>

#define DBHOST "tcp://127.0.0.1:8080"
#define USER "root"
#define PASSWORD "231191"
#define DATABASE "test"

#define NUMOFFSET 100
#define COLNAME 200

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;

static void retrieve_data_and_print (ResultSet *rs, int type, int colidx, string colname) {

/* retrieve the row count in the result set */
cout << "\nRetrieved " << rs -> rowsCount() << " row(s)." << endl;

cout << "\nCityName" << endl;
cout << "--------" << endl;

/* fetch the data : retrieve all the rows in the result set */
while (rs->next()) {
    if (type == NUMOFFSET) {
                   cout << rs -> getString(colidx) << endl;
    } else if (type == COLNAME) {
                   cout << rs -> getString(colname) << endl;
    } // if-else
} // while

cout << endl;

 } // retrieve_data_and_print()

static void retrieve_dbmetadata_and_print (Connection *dbcon) {

if (dbcon -> isClosed()) {
    throw runtime_error("DatabaseMetaData FAILURE - database connection closed");
}

cout << "\nDatabase Metadata" << endl;
cout << "-----------------" << endl;

cout << boolalpha;

/* The following commented statement won't work with Connector/C++ 1.0.5 and later */
//auto_ptr < DatabaseMetaData > dbcon_meta (dbcon -> getMetaData());

DatabaseMetaData *dbcon_meta = dbcon -> getMetaData();

cout << "Database Product Name: " << dbcon_meta -> getDatabaseProductName() << endl;
cout << "Database Product Version: " << dbcon_meta -> getDatabaseProductVersion() << endl;
cout << "Database User Name: " << dbcon_meta -> getUserName() << endl << endl;

cout << "Driver name: " << dbcon_meta -> getDriverName() << endl;
cout << "Driver version: " << dbcon_meta -> getDriverVersion() << endl << endl;

cout << "Database in Read-Only Mode?: " << dbcon_meta -> isReadOnly() << endl;
cout << "Supports Transactions?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsTransactions() << endl;
cout << "Supports DML Transactions only?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsDataManipulationTransactionsOnly() << endl;
cout << "Supports Batch Updates?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsBatchUpdates() << endl;
cout << "Supports Outer Joins?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsOuterJoins() << endl;
cout << "Supports Multiple Transactions?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsMultipleTransactions() << endl;
cout << "Supports Named Parameters?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsNamedParameters() << endl;
cout << "Supports Statement Pooling?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsStatementPooling() << endl;
cout << "Supports Stored Procedures?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsStoredProcedures() << endl;
cout << "Supports Union?: " << dbcon_meta -> supportsUnion() << endl << endl;

cout << "Maximum Connections: " << dbcon_meta -> getMaxConnections() << endl;
cout << "Maximum Columns per Table: " << dbcon_meta -> getMaxColumnsInTable() << endl;
cout << "Maximum Columns per Index: " << dbcon_meta -> getMaxColumnsInIndex() << endl;
cout << "Maximum Row Size per Table: " << dbcon_meta -> getMaxRowSize() << " bytes" << endl;

cout << "\nDatabase schemas: " << endl;

auto_ptr < ResultSet > rs ( dbcon_meta -> getSchemas());

cout << "\nTotal number of schemas = " << rs -> rowsCount() << endl;
cout << endl;

int row = 1;

while (rs -> next()) {
    cout << "\t" << row << ". " << rs -> getString("TABLE_SCHEM") << endl;
    ++row;
} // while

cout << endl << endl;

} // retrieve_dbmetadata_and_print()

static void retrieve_rsmetadata_and_print (ResultSet *rs) {

if (rs -> rowsCount() == 0) {
    throw runtime_error("ResultSetMetaData FAILURE - no records in the result set");
}

cout << "ResultSet Metadata" << endl;
cout << "------------------" << endl;

/* The following commented statement won't work with Connector/C++ 1.0.5 and later */
//auto_ptr < ResultSetMetaData > res_meta ( rs -> getMetaData() );

ResultSetMetaData *res_meta = rs -> getMetaData();

int numcols = res_meta -> getColumnCount();
cout << "\nNumber of columns in the result set = " << numcols << endl << endl;

cout.width(20);
cout << "Column Name/Label";
cout.width(20);
cout << "Column Type";
cout.width(20);
cout << "Column Size" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < numcols; ++i) {
    cout.width(20);
    cout << res_meta -> getColumnLabel (i+1);
    cout.width(20); 
    cout << res_meta -> getColumnTypeName (i+1);
    cout.width(20); 
    cout << res_meta -> getColumnDisplaySize (i+1) << endl << endl;
}

cout << "\nColumn \"" << res_meta -> getColumnLabel(1);
cout << "\" belongs to the Table: \"" << res_meta -> getTableName(1);
cout << "\" which belongs to the Schema: \"" << res_meta -> getSchemaName(1) << "\"" << endl << endl;

} // retrieve_rsmetadata_and_print()


int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

Driver *driver;
Connection *con;
Statement *stmt;
ResultSet *res;
PreparedStatement *prep_stmt;
Savepoint *savept;

int updatecount = 0;

/* initiate url, user, password and database variables */
string url(argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : DBHOST);
const string user(argc >= 3 ? argv[2] : USER);
const string password(argc >= 4 ? argv[3] : PASSWORD);
const string database(argc >= 5 ? argv[4] : DATABASE);

try {
    driver = get_driver_instance();

    /* create a database connection using the Driver */
    con = driver -> connect(url, user, password);

    /* alternate syntax using auto_ptr to create the db connection */
    //auto_ptr  con (driver -> connect(url, user, password));

    /* turn off the autocommit */
    con -> setAutoCommit(0);

    cout << "\nDatabase connection\'s autocommit mode = " << con -> getAutoCommit() << endl;

    /* select appropriate database schema */
    con -> setSchema(database);

    /* retrieve and display the database metadata */
    retrieve_dbmetadata_and_print (con);

    /* create a statement object */
    stmt = con -> createStatement();

    cout << "Executing the Query: \"SELECT * FROM City\" .." << endl;

    /* run a query which returns exactly one result set */
    res = stmt -> executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM City");

    cout << "Retrieving the result set .." << endl;

    /* retrieve the data from the result set and display on stdout */
    retrieve_data_and_print (res, NUMOFFSET, 1, string("CityName"));

    /* retrieve and display the result set metadata */
    retrieve_rsmetadata_and_print (res);

    cout << "Demonstrating Prepared Statements .. " << endl << endl;

    /* insert couple of rows of data into City table using Prepared Statements */
    prep_stmt = con -> prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO City (CityName) VALUES (?)");

    cout << "\tInserting \"London, UK\" into the table, City .." << endl;

    prep_stmt -> setString (1, "London, UK");
    updatecount = prep_stmt -> executeUpdate();

    cout << "\tCreating a save point \"SAVEPT1\" .." << endl;
    savept = con -> setSavepoint ("SAVEPT1");

    cout << "\tInserting \"Paris, France\" into the table, City .." << endl;

    prep_stmt -> setString (1, "Paris, France");
    updatecount = prep_stmt -> executeUpdate();

    cout << "\tRolling back until the last save point \"SAVEPT1\" .." << endl;
    con -> rollback (savept);
    con -> releaseSavepoint (savept);

    cout << "\tCommitting outstanding updates to the database .." << endl;
    con -> commit();

    cout << "\nQuerying the City table again .." << endl;

    /* re-use result set object */
    res = NULL;
    res = stmt -> executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM City");

    /* retrieve the data from the result set and display on stdout */
    retrieve_data_and_print (res, COLNAME, 1, string ("CityName"));

    cout << "Cleaning up the resources .." << endl;

    /* Clean up */
    delete res;
    delete stmt;
    delete prep_stmt;
    con -> close();
    delete con;

} catch (SQLException &e) {
    cout << "ERROR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
    cout << " (" << __func__<< ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
    cout << "ERROR: " << e.what();
    cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
    cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << ")" << endl;

    if (e.getErrorCode() == 1047) {
        /*
        Error: 1047 SQLSTATE: 08S01 (ER_UNKNOWN_COM_ERROR)
        Message: Unknown command
        */
        cout << "\nYour server does not seem to support Prepared Statements at all. ";
        cout << "Perhaps MYSQL < 4.1?" << endl;
    }

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
} catch (std::runtime_error &e) {

    cout << "ERROR: runtime_error in " << __FILE__;
    cout << " (" << __func__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
    cout << "ERROR: " << e.what() << endl;

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} // main()
```

i am using this command to compile:
g++ -I/usr/include/mysql/ -I/usr/include/cppcon/ -L/usr/lib/mysql/ -L/usr/lib -lmysqlclient -lmysqlcppconn MySQLConnectorC++Client.cpp

and getting this as error:
tmp/cc9yx9qf.o: In function `main':
MySQLConnectorC++Client.cpp:(.text+0x1060): undefined reference to`get_driver_instance'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Are you really giving those backslashes on the command line?